# How to use Criteria all in querying mongoDb in java?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDB for my spring-boot application. I need to find the list of documents corresponding to list of IDs.

I have a **Role** collection and a list called **roleIdList**. This list (roleIdList) contains all the role ids whose documents needs to be fetched.

Below is my query:

```
// My roleIdList is of type List<ObjectId>. I also tried with List<String>

Query query = Query.query(where("_id").all(roleIdList));
List<RolesEntity> rolesEntityList = mongoOperations.find(query, RolesEntity.class);
```

But with the above query, I am getting empty rolesEntityList. Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in` instead of `all`

`Query query = Query.query(where("_id").in(roleIdList));`

See:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Answer (score 0):

you can also use: `List<RolesEntity> findByRole_IdIn(List<String> roleIdList)`